# How would I calculate time left in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi any ideas on how to calculate time left to a specific hour,
i.e. we start countdown with
`if currentTime >= TimeSpan.Parse("06:40") && currentTime <= TimeSpan.Parse("07:25")`
and then we parse current hour and end hour (in this example 7:25) and make a label show how many minutes and seconds are left.
I've tried making something with substracting timespan now and end time timespan but it didn't work out at all.

EDIT: The main idea is something like this, but I can't get it to work by using TimeSpan neither DateTime

```
string myTime;

void timer()
    {
        var endTime = DateTime.Parse(myTime);
        var beginTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    }

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var endTime = DateTime.Parse(myTime);
        var beginTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        TimeSpan difference = endTime - beginTime;
        TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        if (currentTime >= TimeSpan.Parse("06:40") && currentTime <= TimeSpan.Parse("07:25"))
        {
            label5.Text = "0";
            myTime = "07:25";
            timer();
            label6.Text = difference;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us compilable code (like having an if statement with parentheses)?  I'm assuming that `currentTime` is a DateTime.  If so, you can't compare a DateTime with a TimeSpan.  What are you really trying to do?  In general, you should work with DateTime and TimeSpan quantities (initializing them with constructors or static methods (other than `.Parse`), and then convert them to strings only when you need to display them to users

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are asking about. Of course subtracting two TimeSpans will work; it will produce another TimeSpan indicating the delta between the two TimeSpans you subtracted. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem you have.

Comment: Post some of your code and add some more details

Comment: Added some code. Hope it will make whole thing easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DateTime instead of TimeSpan when parsing points in time. TimeSpan is for durations. The difference between two points in time (DateTime) will be a duration (TimeSpan).

```
var end = DateTime.Parse("21:00");
var now = DateTime.Now;      // Could also be some other point in time
TimeSpan timeLeft = end-now;
Console.WriteLine(timeLeft);
```

Result:

> 00:24:25.8581440

If you don't like the seconds and fractions of seconds, you can use a [custom format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings), e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(timeLeft.ToString("hh\\:mm"));
```

Comment: That seems to work but the problem is that I need to display time left as text of a label and not just in console, and visual studio won't let me convert TimeSpan to string.

Comment: @user10665024: did you see that `timeLeft.ToString()` piece of code? That's a string. You can use it anywhere.

Comment: Oh actually I missed it somehow. I'll try it out thanks!